# How to locate exact element? For all the elements same HTML code is present

Tags: python, selenium

Here, For all the elements same fields are available.

I have used xpath here to locate it thought text i.e.

`('//mat-label[text()="Domain"]/.. /.. /../input')` but it locates all the elements which contains text as '`Domain`'.

I need help to find out how I can exactly locate element which I want to select and edit for?

Please help me with this.`

> [enter image description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVh22FJv9aTxPEnCn_nGIECf2CcMehXr/view?usp=sharing)  Please use below link for HTML code.

> [Blockquote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hb8gdD1eL7KhsNLDJBBTY3pLD9r2OipD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: And need to understand how this can be automated.

Comment: How many entries does this have `//mat-label[text()='Domain']` ? also if page url is public share with us.

Comment: almost 10 entries we have. Page is not public hence I have copied the HTML code here.

Comment: Can find a link of HTML code,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVh22FJv9aTxPEnCn_nGIECf2CcMehXr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: link for video of the flow:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fyIBt6qRMbsHR_ThSvBgu5F08iTLQ4bY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have shared a pic, I cannot read it from pic for 10 elements, try posting HTML in text format.

Comment: HTML code in text format.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1acHlkjkFKVcUn4N0-UjFnB5NScJfg6dv/view?usp=sharing

Please do have a look on attached video link also to understand the functional flow.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fyIBt6qRMbsHR_ThSvBgu5F08iTLQ4bY/view?usp=sharing

Need to automate as same as shown in Video

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9444073/cruisepandey

did you get a chance to see it?  :)